# How to do many SQL queries in a for loop with Nodejs and Express

Tags: javascript, sql, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a req.body from a Post form with many values like this

```
console.log(req.body)

{

productid:[1, 2, 3]
qty: [3, 5, 6]

}
```

I want to make a for loop and use the different values in a SQL query But I get stuck on the first query problaby because its an async await function.

My question is how can I do many sql queries with a forloop and still use an async await function?

Comment: Please edit your question to post what you have tried so we may best assist you in fixing it

Comment: Rethink your approach. Round trips to the database are expensive. Instead of writing a loop in code that executed a query against the database for each value, you should execute one query that will return all of the results you need.

Instead of 3 queries where productid = x , you should be submitting 1 query where productid IN (1,2,3). Then you get one result set back and can iterate through them.

This post is seriously lacking in details. No one can give you anything more than vague answers to a vague question.

Comment: Please join to [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135158/chat-with-mvb17816702) to see answer to your "10 blocks" question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
for(let item of array) {
   let res = await query(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I only do an update and not waiting for an answer I didnt need to use await async. It worked when I remove async/await.

Thank you

Sorry for not so clear question

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do them in parallel you can create an array of promises and use Promise.all to wait for all the operations to finish, in this way you can optimize you code a lot instead of doing in a sequential way.

```
    const operations = []
    for(let item of array) {
      operations.push(query(item))
    }
    const result = await Promise.all(operations)
    //Do wherever you want with your results.
```

In order to execute your code, your function which handle the request must be declared with the async keyword.